# Oversized credit card icons in WooCommerce backend

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, credit-card

The credit card icons on the WooCommerce Orders back-end page are suddenly very large.

How would I write CSS to reduce those icons back down to something like 32px wide?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XOQq.jpg

Comment: Please improve your question. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1):

You can give the icon the width of 32px

HTML:

```
<img src="#" class="exampleClass">
```

CSS:

```
.exampleClass {
  width: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that simple to write CSS to the back-end.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't google WooCommerce. I don't know much about WordPress but when you can access the html-side you can use queryselectors.